# replacing space in column data with '|' symbol not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
            'id': ['1001','1002','1003','1004'],
            'colA': ['H','L B','L H','L B'],
            'colB': ['H','L|B','L|H','L|B']
    }
 )
```

I want to replace the `|` in `colB` with space and I tried the following code, but it's not working. It worked when the case was vice verse (replacing space with |). How can I get it work?

```
df['colB'] = df['colB'].replace('|', ' ')
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`.str` to access](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html#pandas-series-str) the string functions.

```
df['colB'] = df['colB'].str.replace('|', ' ')
```

Demo

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
...     {
...             'id': ['1001','1002','1003','1004'],
...             'colA': ['H','L B','L H','L B'],
...             'colB': ['H','L|B','L|H','L|B']
...     }
...  )
>>>
>>> df
     id colA colB
0  1001    H    H
1  1002  L B  L|B
2  1003  L H  L|H
3  1004  L B  L|B
>>>
>>> df['colB'] = df['colB'].str.replace('|', ' ')
>>> df
     id colA colB
0  1001    H    H
1  1002  L B  L B
2  1003  L H  L H
3  1004  L B  L B
```

If you don't want to use string function, You can still use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html#pandas-series-replace) but with `regex=True.`

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
...     {
...             'id': ['1001','1002','1003','1004'],
...             'colA': ['H','L B','L H','L B'],
...             'colB': ['H','L|B','L|H','L|B']
...     }
...  )
>>>
>>> df
     id colA colB
0  1001    H    H
1  1002  L B  L|B
2  1003  L H  L|H
3  1004  L B  L|B
>>> df['colB'] = df['colB'].replace(r'\|', ' ', regex=True)
>>> df
     id colA colB
0  1001    H    H
1  1002  L B  L B
2  1003  L H  L H
3  1004  L B  L B
```

Comment: Also set regex to false: `df['colB'].str.replace(r'|', ' ', regex=False)`

Comment: @sunnytown `regex=False` by default. No?

Comment: Not yet, `regex=True` is deprecated but still the default for the current version.